# Speed of objects travelling down liquid-filled tubes of different widths

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, drag, viscosity

Consider I have two tubes filled with water: Tube A and Tube B. Tube A has a diameter of 20mm and Tube B has a diameter of 10mm. A marble ball with a diameter 8mm is dropped down both tubes.

Why does the marble ball fall slower in Tube B than Tube A?

Answer (score 0):

If the marble is centered in the smaller tube, the water must flow upwards through an annular channel of width 1mm as it is displaced by the falling marble.  At this scale, the viscosity of the water can’t be ignored. In a sufficiently large tube, the marble would just fall at the terminal velocity for glass in water.

For a circular tube with area $A=\pi r^2$ and a pressure difference $\Delta p$ across its length $\ell$, Poiseuille’s Law gives a volume flow rate $Q\propto \Delta p \,A^2/\ell \eta$, where the viscosity $\eta$ has units of pascal-seconds.  I don’t know the relation for an annular channel or for a sphere-in-cylinder constriction, but the area-squared-per-length proportionality will probably survive thanks to dimensional analysis. In your example, the annulus in the larger tube has an order of magnitude more area.

Compare to the historical example of the “proof” that it is “impossible” for a bumblebee to fly, which was solved when aerodynamic modeling became sophisticated enough to account for deformable wings in viscous air.